# (Windows Powershell) How to open a globally defined file with a certain application?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell

I've added the `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\` directory, which contains the windows `hosts`-file, to my PATH environment.

So if I start the shell at some arbitrary location (`C:\` for example) and execute `C:\> hosts` some window pops up, asking me which program I want to use to open this file, as expected.

However, when I execute the following command:

```
C:\> notepad hosts
```

I get a popup from notepad saying that this file doesn't exist (and it asks me if I want to create it).

How can I make it such that it opens the actual `hosts` file with notepad whenever I run this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can declare a function like this:

```
function host(){
    notepad C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
}
```

so each time you write hosts it open the file with notepad.

and you can add the function to your powershell profile to make it persistant

Comment: I've just added this to my PowerShell Profile and it works great. Thanks!